# Want to link to the same table multiple times as the id keeps changing

Tags: sql, oracle

I need audit information from my quote database, `quote_num` and `RV_changed_by`.

A new `quote_num` is assigned every time someone makes a copy of the quote. The previous `quote_num` is stored in `parent_quote_num`.

However `RV_changed_by` is not 'moved' to the new `quote_num`.

E.g. `quote_num = 1234`, I changed the RV and save the quote. Now `RV_changed_by = 'mobenator'`.
User A then copies `quote_num` 1234, now `quote_num = 2345`, `RV_changed_by = null`, `parent_quote_num = 1234`.

I can link `quote_num` to `parent_quote_num` and get the `RV_changed_by` from 1234. However I need retrieve the `RV_changed_by` for thousands of quotes, each of which could have a populated `RV_changed_by` for any number of historical copies.

Is there a way of looping through the `quote_num` to `parent_quote_num`, storing `RV_changed_by` until `parent_quote_num = null`?

Additionally `RV_changed_by` could be in multiple historic `quote_nums`, however the most recent is the most relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Example data

In the instance below I would like to print ***quote_num*** **5555** and the ***RV_changed_by*** from ***quote_num*** **2222**. Looping back though the ***parent_quote_nums*** to find one where ***RV_changed_by*** != **null**.

```
quote_num    parent_quote_num    RV_changed_by
2222         1111                mobenator
3333         2222                null
4444         3333                null
5555         4444                null
```

Other info
Oracle Database 12c
PL/SQL (which I think is TSQL)

Comment: Hi Mobenator, could you give us a sample of data and an example of the data you expect to be returned, please?  Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: It would be a good idea to take the [tour], and read the [help] pages.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. I can't share any data I'm afraid because my network won't let me access fireshare or pastebin like sites. Currently I have extracted the raw data in Excel, then in VBA I then query the data and loop until all parent numbers are null. This takes a long time (four hours) because each join has to re-join the 3,000 quotes I'm interested in to 300,0000 parent quotes.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: If you copy just a few lines from your Excel worksheet you should be able to [paste it in to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63880410/edit) (it's just a sample so people can see what they're dealing with).

Comment: Also, what flavour of SQL are we dealing with?  You should add a tag to the list so that people can provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: From what you've described, I imagine you will need a recursive query but depending on what DB (and version) you're using, it may or may not have recursive support and the syntax of the SQL will vary, so it's important to state what your SQL environment is along with the question.

Comment: As per @user9601310's comment above, you could try using [Recursive CTEs](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/) to achieve your ends.

Comment: Thanks for the sample data.  Still needs the DB and version to be able to provide a suitable answer though!

Comment: Thanks everyone! I don't know if this is what you mean by DB and version, Oracle Database 12c, PL/SQL (which I think is TSQL). I know what I can do in SQL but I don't know how it all works together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte( orig_quote_num, quote_num, parent_quote_num, RV_changed_by, lev ) as (
      select quote_num as orig_quote_num, quote_num, parent_quote_num, RV_changed_by, 1 as lev
      from t
      where quote_num = 5555
      union all
      select cte.orig_quote_num, t.quote_num, t.parent_quote_num, t.RV_changed_by, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.quote_num = cte.parent_quote_num
     )
select *
from cte
where RV_changed_by is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76ca53efccc16a2baf21119bfcaeaeda) is a db<>fiddle.